# Can't find MySQL database folders

Tags: php, mysql, database, mamp, mamp-pro

Since migrating to a new Mac a few weeks ago, I have happily set up MAMP and MAMP Pro on my new machine, migrated my local website folders and at some point I must have pointed my databases to the right location to get the majority of my local websites working.

The problem came when I tried to run one of my local web applications and got an internal server error (it couldn't find the database).

I do have a backup of all my database folders from my old Mac (with all the .frm, .myd, .myi) files but I can no longer seem to find the correct location for the new databases.

I am currently using MAMP Pro and in the /appsolute/MAMPPRO folder there are no databases and yet most of my database-dependent sites are running without issue.

I guess my question is, "How can I find where localhost is searching for/ saving databases to so that I can re-add my old database folders?"

If anyone has any clue to this, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look in the my.ini/my.cnf file. it'll specify the data dir. It can also be specified as a command-line arg to the mysqld daemon. e.g. `[mysqld] datadir=/blah/blah/blah`

Comment: If you installed the official package from MySQL the default is /usr/local/mysql/data

Comment: What language are you using php? etc , Im not sure if you can find it on localhost. but I think you should try importing your data via the command line its much better and more effecient

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. Yes I'm using PHP. As I have previously used MAMP, MAMP Pro and AMPPS also in the past (though not on this computer), I'm in a bit of a pickle as to what is where anymore. I will check the my.ini file. Thanks

Comment: on my.cnf I have the following "You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options."

In that folder I can see the majority of my database folders, including one of my application that can't locate the database although interestingly, new databases that are working, aren't showing up in there!

Comment: can you start MySQL command line interface? If so, then check `show variables like 'datadir';`

Comment: Thanks Barranka, could you give me an example of how i'd enter that to Terminal?

Comment: Update: bash can't seem to locate mysql, yet it's obviously installed as most of my db applications are running

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, on OS X MySQL binnaries are installed in `usr/local/mysql/bin`. So if you want to use the MySQL command-line interface you should type in your terminal:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -h yourHost -u yourUser -p
```

(If you are working on `localhost` substitute `yourHost` with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`)

If your MySQL distribution is installed elsewhere, check the documentation and input the appropriate path. Check the documentation for your MAMP stack... or, if you want to do it the hard way, you can look the path "by hand" with this:

```
ls -lR / | grep -i 'mysql'
```

(if the list is too long, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop it)

Once you enter the MySQL command-line interface, enter this query to see the path of the data folder:

```
show variables like 'datadir';
```

Answer (score 0):

MAMP is using this mysql database:
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql

MAMP PRO is using this databse:
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql

not too sure if this helps, but your databases should be in either dir